# NSLayoutConstraint VFL crashes because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

The app that I am working on has so many visual formatted constraints. After I bunched up some network request in one operation I started getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. I don't get any crash if I create constraints manually by the NSLayoutConstraint(item.... ) initializer.

Here is the line where the crash happens in my code:

[image]

And here is the crash log:
[image]

What could cause this crash? and How can I fix it?

Comment: This basically looks fine (see unrelated caveat below). It works for me. Where are you calling this `addConstraints`? Obviously, it must be in a `UIView` subclass, but where precisely are you doing this? Bottom line, we need a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot reproduce the problem on the basis of what you've provided here.

Comment: Unrelated, generally you'd say `options: []`. The `NSLayoutFormatOptions` is a `OptionSet`, and and empty set is just `[]`. In fact, with the `constraints` method, that `options` parameter is optional, defaulting to `[]`, so you can even omit `options: []` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue when creating an array of NSLayoutConstraints then activating all at once from the array.

When you navigate to away from a view then come back to it, sometimes the view can be assigned to a different allocation of memory and cause the Bad Access Error.

Here's what happens.  New constraints are added to the array every time the view loads (assuming you add them and activate them from the `.viewDidLoad()` function or from a similar function that loads every time the view becomes visible again).

The array doesn't empty itself when you navigate away from it so the old constraints also remain in the array.  When you navigate back to the view and attempt to activate the constraints, the system attempts to activate the old constraints again (which are referencing memory that doesn't contain any of the views your constraints are referencing anymore).

To fix this, call `.RemoveAll()` on your array before you add the new constraints to it.  This will make sure all of the old constraints are removed and the system won't try to activate them.

Here's an example.

```
var initialConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Empty the array once the view loads
    initialConstraints.removeAll()

    // Add your constraints like normal
    initialConstraints.append(...)

    // Activate your constraints once you've added them to the array (like normal)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(initialConstraints)

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How does view load itself multiple times?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention - it happened for me when I navigated from one tab to another then back to the original.

Comment: But navigating between tabs should not trigger viewDidLoad unless you are calling them on purpose

Comment: In my app, placing a breakpoint inside of viewDidLoad shows that it's called each time I navigate to the tab and I am not calling the .viewDidLoad function in my own code.

How did you end up solving the issue?

Comment: I couldn't solve it I had to construct all the Visual formatted constraints with NSLayoutContraint.init method